# Assigning header names to panda datasheets with varying number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to assign a header row to panda dataframes with a varying number of columns. The underlying data sheet are targets disclosed by companies, the number of which differ per company

Eg. this could be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['apple','become carbon neutral','100% renewable'],['Microsoft','carbon neutral','']])

0      apple  become carbon neutral  100% renewable
1  Microsoft         carbon neutral
```

Or

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['nike','set up foundation'],['Amazon','more energy efficient']])
0      nike  set up foundation  
1  amazon         more energy efficient
```

The header row should hence be:

```
company name, target 1, target 2, target 3, target 4 etc.
```

What is the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming default column names `0`, `1`, `2` etc:

```
df.columns = ['company name', *map('target {}'.format, df.columns[1:])]
```

Or based on a `range` if columns are already named:

```
df.columns = ['company name', *map('target {}'.format, range(1, len(df.columns)))]
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['apple', 'become carbon neutral', '100% renewable'],
                   ['Microsoft', 'carbon neutral', '']])

df.columns = ['company name', *map('target {}'.format, range(1, len(df.columns)))]
print(df)
```

`df`:

```
  company name               target 1        target 2
0        apple  become carbon neutral  100% renewable
1    Microsoft         carbon neutral
```